# Generate images in pure Swift, without UIKit?

Tags: swift, core-graphics

Is it possible to generate images in pure Swift? Let's say I want to make a CLI app that draws text on top of an image, and I also want it to run on Linux, is this possible at all? Or should my Swift CLI app just call out to an external app, for example written in Python, to generate the image.

Comment: You mean without the use of any framework like UIKit or AppKit, I don't see how that is possible.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was afraid of that as well :/

Comment: You can write custom GPU kernels in Swift but I don't know if you can achieve something like that easily

Comment: I already wrote a Python script using Pillow to do what I need, and am calling that from my Swift app. Works fine, just too bad this is needed. I wish Swift was more general purpose like Python.